# Add HTTPS to already existing Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules and conditions in my `mod_rewrite` and like to add HTTPS to it. I like to confirm the following it accurate before publishing it live.

**Current Rules and Conditions**

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.jpg$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* /home/domain.com/public_html/missing.png [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

**New Rules and Conditions**

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.jpg$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* /home/domain.com/public_html/missing.png [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ https://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Independent from your question, but this won't work unless you have a _really_ exotic setup: `RewriteRule .* /home/domain.com/public_html/missing.png [L]`. That looks like an absolute path in your file system, but that is not what will work inside a `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Has to as it is in place now and working. If an image is missing it is currently inserting that missing image.

Comment: If you say so... but I would be surprised: that is against what is documented. There it says that you indeed _can_ use an absolute file system path as target in rewrite rules (though that is ambiguous and should not be done), but it will only work in the vhost configuration, _not_ in `.htaccess` style files as you claim you are using.

Comment: I tried both and both work. I do not have it in `.htaccess` I have all this in `apache`.

Comment: Ah, ok that is different. I assumed you are using `.htaccess` style files since you tagged your question that way. I see you removed that tag. Have fun!

Comment: Seeing that both work, this one is the better option? `RewriteRule .* /missing.png [L]` I can change it. I got it off a site somewhere and been using it for 3 to 4 years.

Comment: I personally think using one strategy is better than mixing two, so I would answer "yes". But the difference is small. The ambiguity issue is only theoretical if you had a path like `/home/domain.com/public_html` published as URL. This is most likely not the case. So as you like. My point was to warn you that this won't work in `.htaccess` style files, that is sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# always do domain/https redirs first
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.domain\.com$). [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S+\s+/?(\S*)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com/%1 [NS,NE,L,R=301]
# remove index files from URLs, except from POST forms, etc. you can add more file extensions to the second condition
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(?:GET|HEAD)$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S+\s+/?((?:[^?/]*/)*?)index\.(?:html?|php|pl)(\?\S*)?(?:\s|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com/%1%2 [NS,NE,L,R=301] 
# missing images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$ /missing.png [NS,NC,L,DPI]
```

Comment: Sorry it took this long; just went live with new SSL today. Thanks for the perfect solution.

Comment: Updated it. Other version worked -- the new version above does as well. Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, but it had a significant failing case for removing the index file, and was less efficient.